# Inverse function theorem: Lemma 5 from Terence Tao's blog

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

I'm trying to understand the proof of *Lemma 5* from Terence Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/), i.e.,

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f:X \to \mathbb R^n$ be differentiable such that $\partial f (x)$ is invertible for all $x\in X$. Fix $x_0 \in X$ and $y_0 := f(x_0)$ and let
$$
K := \{x \in X: f(x)=y_0\}.
$$

> **Lemma 5:** Let $H$ be the connected component of $K$ that contains $x_0$. Then $H = \{x_0\}$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

**Proof:** Assume the contrary that $H \neq \{x_0\}$. Then there is a path $\gamma:[0,1] \to H$ such that $\gamma(0) = x_0$ and $\gamma(1) \in H \setminus \{x_0\}$. We have $f \circ \gamma = y_0$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{f \circ \gamma (t) - f(x_0) - \partial f (x_0)(\gamma(t)-x_0)}{|\gamma(t)-x_0|} &= -\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{ \partial f (x_0)(\gamma(t)-x_0)}{|\gamma(t)-x_0|} \\
&= - \partial f (x_0) \left (\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{\gamma(t)-x_0}{|\gamma(t)-x_0|} \right ).
\end{align}
$$

Because $\partial f (x_0)$ is invertible, it is bijective. It follows that
$$
\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{\gamma(t)-x_0}{|\gamma(t)-x_0|} = 0,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Are you deducing the existence of the path $\gamma$ from the connectedness of $H$ alone? Note that $H$ being connected doesn't imply it is path-connected.

Comment: @user85667 You're right! Do you have any idea for a fix?

Comment: Well, I would be lazy and apply the inverse function theorem. There are neighborhoods of $x_0$ and $y_0$ on which $f$ has an inverse. In particular, the restriction of $f$ to the neighborhood of $x_0$ is injective and therefore there are no other points of $H$ in it.

Comment: @user85667 but $f$ is not $C^1$...

Comment: @user85667 I may be wrong, but Rolle's theorem applies to only real-valued functions.

Comment: Let $A$ be the differential of $f$ at $x_0$. Since it is non-singular then there is some positive constant $c>0$ (the norm of its inverse) such that $\|Ax\|\geq c\|x\|$. Let $x_n\to x_0$ be points where $f(x_n)=f(x_0)$. We have that $0=f(x_n)-f(x_0)=A(x_0-x_n)+R(x_0-x_n)$, where $R$ satisfies $\|R(x)\|/\|x\|\to0$ as $x\to0$. Then $\|R(x_0-x_n)\|=\|A(x_0-x_n)\|\geq c\|x_0-x_n\|$. If we divide by $\|x_0-x_n\|$ and let $n\to\infty$, we would get $0\geq c$, which is a contradiction with $c>0$. Therefore $x_0$ is an isolated point of $K$.

Comment: @user85667 Thank you so much for your help! Could you check my answer below to see if I understand your idea correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formulate @user85667's idea below to better understand it.

---

Assume the contrary that $H$ has an element other than $x_0$.

> [Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543461/a-continuous-linear-map-is-bounded-from-below-if-and-only-if-it-is-injective-and) Let $E, F$ be Banach spaces and $f:E \to F$ linear continuous. Then $f$ is bounded from below, i.e.,
> $$
> \exists c>0, \forall x \in E: |f(x)| \ge c |x|,
> $$
> if and only if $f$ is injective and has closed range.

Let $A := \partial f (x_0)$. Then $A$ is invertible. By **Lemma 1**, there is $c>0$ such that $|A (x)| \ge c|x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

> [Theorem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543482/a-connected-metric-space-e-d-with-at-least-2-points-has-no-isolated-point) A connected metric space $(E, d)$ with at least $2$ points has no isolated points.

By **Lemma 2**, $H$ has no isolated points. So there is $(x_n)_{n\ge 1} \subset H \setminus \{x_0\}$ such that $x_n \to x_0$. Because $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$,
$$
f(x)-f(x_0) = A(x-x_0) + o (|x-x_0|) \quad \text{as} \quad x \to x_0.
$$

Notice that $x_n \in H$ and thus $f(x_n)=y_0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, so
$$
A(x_n-x_0) =- o (|x-x_0|) \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|A(x_n-x_0)|}{|x_n -x_0|} \ge c>0,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, although Lemma 1 is more general than needed. We only need the bound in finite dimension, which we can just get from something as simple as the triangle inequality $\|A^{-1}x\|^2\leq n^2\max_{i,j}(|a_{i,j}|^2)\|x\|^2$.

Comment: @user85667 Thank you so much for your dedicated help!