# A connected metric space $(E, d)$ with at least $2$ points has no isolated points

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, connectedness

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543154/inverse-function-theorem-a-lemma-from-from-terence-taos-blog?noredirect=1#comment9553456_4543154) comment appeals to a property of connected component in $\mathbb R^n$. I'm trying to see how it works. This property was also mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535302/a-connected-subset-of-a-metric-space-with-at-least-two-points-has-no-isolated-po) thread.

> **Theorem:** A connected metric space $(E, d)$ with at least $2$ points has no isolated points.

Could you confirm if my below reasoning is correct?

**Proof:** Assume $a \in E$ is an isolated point of $E$. Fix $b\in E \setminus \{a\}$. There is $r>0$ such that $X :=B(a, r) = \{a\}$, which is both closed and open. On the other hand, $X \notin \{E, \emptyset \}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: This is good. Alternatively, you can say that both $\{a\}$ and $E\setminus \{a\}$ are open, so that $E=\{a\}\cup(E\setminus \{a\})$ is a disconnection of $E$, and $E$ is thus not connected.